# Java FreeMarker: Replacing a ${variable} with a collection instead of an instance of an object

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I'm new to [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_quickstart.html) and I'm trying to build an HTML file for reporting purposes.

I'm able to grasp the basics - like replacing a certain ${user} variable with an object.

**Problem:**
I m trying to create an HTML table using the below template. The `${summaryTable.rowData}` is to be replaced by a series of `<tr>`'s. 1 tr is 1 instance of an object. I can't make this happen using the code below and instead I'm only getting the last instance from the loop.

What am I missing here?

Please see the details below.

**Template:**

```
....
            <thead>
               <tr id="header">
                  <td><b>Module</b></font></td>
                  <td><b>Passed</b></font></td>
                  <td<b>Failed</b></font></td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               ${summaryTable.rowData}
            </tbody>
...
```

**Code:**

```
        // Start Building HTML
        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Header variables
        root.put("environment", envDir);
        root.put("reportDateTimeStamp", dateDir);

        // Summary Table
        for (String module : getAllModules(rawResult)) {
            SummaryTable summaryTable = new SummaryTable();
            int modPassed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelPassed);
            int modFailed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelFailed);

            summaryTable.setRowData(
                    getSummaryData(module, Integer.toString(modPassed), Integer.toString(modFailed)));
            root.put("summaryTable", summaryTable);
        }

        DetailsTable detailsTable = new DetailsTable();
        detailsTable.setRowData(getDetailsData("MOD1", "TC01", "Description 01", "Passed", "00:00:00"));

        root.put("detailsTable", detailsTable);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(htmlResultFile);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charSet);
        temp.process(root, out);
        out.close();
```

The `setRowData()` accepts a single string - in this case, 1 instance of `<tr>` containing N number of `<td>` per `module` iteration.

**Model:**

```
public static class SummaryTable {
    private String rowData;

    public String getRowData() {
        return rowData;
    }

    public void setRowData(String rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }
}
```

**Output:**
Actual:
 [image: Actual] 
Expected:
 [image: Expected]

========================================================================
**UPDATE 1:**
I've updated both my template, code and model based on rrobby's answer below.

**Template:**

```
....
            <thead>
               <tr id="header">
                  <td><b>Module</b></font></td>
                  <td><b>Passed</b></font></td>
                  <td<b>Failed</b></font></td>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <#list summaryTable as summaryTable.rowData>
                <tr>
                ${summaryTable.rowData}
                </tr>
               </#list>
            </tbody>
...
```

**Code:**

```
        // Start Building HTML
        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        // Header variables
        root.put("environment", envDir);
        root.put("reportDateTimeStamp", dateDir);

        // Summary Table
        ArrayList<SummaryTable> summaryTable = new ArrayList<SummaryTable>();
        for (String module : getAllModules(rawResult)) {
            int modPassed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelPassed);
            int modFailed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelFailed);

            summaryTable.add(new SummaryTable(
                    getSummaryData(module, Integer.toString(modPassed), Integer.toString(modFailed))));
        }
        root.put("summaryTable", summaryTable);

        DetailsTable detailsTable = new DetailsTable();
        detailsTable.setRowData(getDetailsData("MOD1", "TC01", "Description 01", "Passed", "00:00:00"));

        root.put("detailsTable", detailsTable);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(htmlResultFile);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charSet);
        temp.process(root, out);
        out.close();
```

The `setRowData()` accepts a single string - in this case, 1 instance of `<tr>` containing N number of `<td>` per `module` iteration.

**Model:**

```
public static class SummaryTable {
    private String rowData;

    public String getRowData() {
        return rowData;
    }

    public void setRowData(String rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }

    public SummaryTable(String rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "ReportTemplate.html" in line 100, column 63:
Encountered ".", but was expecting one of:
    ","
    ">"
```

line 100 points to `<#list summaryTable as summaryTable.rowData>`

Hope you can help.

Comment: I recommend reading through the whole "Quick start" which you have linked. See the section about `#list` in http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html in this case. Pretty much all you do in typical templates is `${...}` `#if/#elseif/#else` and `#list` (and its companions, `#items`/`#else` and `#sep`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this to work. Rrobby's tip helped but his answer is not quite completely there.

**Template (Syntax):**

```
    <tbody>
       <#list yourObject as anyVariable>
       <tr>
          ${anyVariable.aPropertyOfYourObject}
       </tr>
       </#list>
    </tbody>
```

**Template (Actual):**

```
    <tbody>
       <#list summaryTable as summaryData>
       <tr>
          ${summaryData.rowData}
       </tr>
       </#list>
    </tbody>
```

**Code:**

```
// Summary Table
ArrayList<SummaryTable> summaryTable = new ArrayList<SummaryTable>();
for (String module : getAllModules(rawResult)) {
    int modPassed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelPassed);
    int modFailed = getModulePassFailCount(rawResult, module).get(GlobalUtil.reportLabelFailed);

    summaryTable.add(new SummaryTable(
            getSummaryData(module, Integer.toString(modPassed), Integer.toString(modFailed))));
    root.put("summaryTable", summaryTable);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public static class SummaryTable {
    private String rowData;

    public String getRowData() {
        return rowData;
    }

    public void setRowData(String rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }

    public SummaryTable(String rowData) {
        this.rowData = rowData;
    }
}
```

I'm using the `#list` directive incorrectly and I needed to place the `root.put("summaryTable", summaryTable);` inside the loop.

Got the correct output after the changes. Thanks for those who helped!

Answer (score 1):

For lists and tables, you should generally put items in a collection and iterate through it with the `<#list>` tag, explained [here](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html).

For example:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <#list summaryTable as row>
      <tr><td>${row.foo}</td><td>${row.bar}</td>...</tr>
    </#list>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm modifying my template now and abot to run some tests. Would really appreciate it if you can layout the syntax for the code part while I try to figure it out. The link you gave did not give that part. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated the question with my recent changes. PS: thanks for the patience. Literally started using FreeMarker a few hours back.

Comment: After `as` in the list tag you should use a simple variable name (not something like `a.b`), which just acts as a placeholder for the value of each row. You should change your updated template to `<#list summaryTable as row><tr>${row}</tr></#list>`.